# Blender Bend Deform Bot Working

Tags: modifiers

[image]

I'm trying to make a circle with the bend modifier around Z axis, but I've got this. Any help, please?

Comment: Why don't you add a circle with <kbd>SHIFT+A</kbd> and extrude it?

Comment: You need to subdivide before bend.

Comment: How is the bend modifier supposed to make a circle out of a triangle?

Comment: its a subdivided long cuboid form, the modifier stransforms it into a triangle